# Python: Moving through record in an array

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I have written a program that imports information from a CSV to a list. I am now trying to write code that allows for the records in said list to be displayed on the screen and have the ability to go through them one by one. I have been able to code the ability to go forward one at a time and loop back to the first array when you move forward on the last record and looping from the first record to the last when moving back from the first record
. 
My problem is that my code to move back one record when not displaying the first record is not working at all. Any help would be appreciated.

```
x=0
count=0
while x==0:
    response=int(raw_input("Enter 1 to see the next record, 2 to see the previous record or 3 to end the program:"))
    print""
    if response==1 and count<len(plain_text):
        print("Record {0}:".format(count+1))
        print("Latitude: {0}  Longitude: {1}  Unencrypted Text: {2} Encrypted Text: {3}".format(latitude[count],longitude[count], plain_text[count], encrypted_text[count]))
        print""
        count=count+1
    elif response==1 and count==len(plain_text):
        print("Record {0}:".format(count+1))
        print("Latitude: {0}  Longitude: {1}  Unencrypted Text: {2} Encrypted Text: {3}".format(latitude[0],longitude[0], plain_text[0], encrypted_text[0]))
        print""
        count=0
    elif response==2 and count==0:
        print("Record {0}:".format(count+1))
        print("Latitude: {0}  Longitude: {1}  Unencrypted Text: {2} Encrypted Text: {3}".format(latitude[4],longitude[4], plain_text[4], encrypted_text[4]))
        print""
        count=4
    if response==2 and count>len(plain_text):
        print("Record {0}:".format(count+1))
        print("Latitude: {0}  Longitude: {1}  Unencrypted Text: {2} Encrypted Text: {3}".format(latitude[count],longitude[count], plain_text[count], encrypted_text[count]))
        print""
        count=count-1
    elif response==3:
        x=1
    elif response>3:
        print ("Please respond with one of the set responses.")
```

Comment: What is `plain_text`?

Comment: a list i had created earlier on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simplify:

```
while True:
    response=int(raw_input("Enter 1 to see the next record, 2 to see the previous record or 3 to end the program:"))
    print""
    if response > 3:
        print ("Please respond with one of the set responses.")        
    elif response == 3:
        break
    else
        if response==1:
            count += 1
            if count >= len(plain_text):
                count = 0
        elif response==2:
            count -= 1
            if count < 0:
                count = len(plain_text) - 1
        print("Record {0}:".format(count))
        print("Latitude: {0}  Longitude: {1}  Unencrypted Text: {2} Encrypted Text: {3}".format(latitude[count],longitude[count], plain_text[count], encrypted_text[count]))
```